# Is this package.json file well formatted with this dependencies

Tags: angular, npm

I'm starting with Angular 2. I not really familiarized with the package.json yet.

I'm having some problems with imports. When I started to do a review in the files I saw I have @angular but also I have angular2 in my dependencies.

Is this package.json well formated ?

```
{
  "name": "Sample",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/forms": "0.3.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.5",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17", <--- Is this right?
    "bootstrap": "3.3.6",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.33.3",
    "jquery": "2.1.4",
    "ng2-modal": "0.0.17",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.0",
    "systemjs": "0.19.6",
    "zone.js": "0.5.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "3.8.11",
    "gulp-concat": "2.5.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "0.1.7",
    "gulp-uglify": "1.2.0",
    "gulp-rename": "1.2.2",
    "rimraf": "2.2.8",
    "lodash": "3.10.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "-vs-binding": {
    "Clean": [
      "tsc"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to the `angular2` issue, the versions of `rxjs` and `zone.js` appear to be too old for Angular 2 RC5. I would use the versions listed [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.5/package.json#L20-L25).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not. [`angular2` package has migrated to `@angular` scope.](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-rc0-2016-05-02)

```
npm uninstall -S angular2
```

And it should be fine.